# How to validate custom fields for a custom post type before insert?

Tags: custom-post-types, validation

I'd like to know how to validate custom fields and return error notice (if necessary) before a custom post type is inserted into the database.

After a little research I found one similar question dating back ~10 years ago, I was hoping for a solution now, it seems like a pretty simple filter to implement.

Looking at `wp-includes/post.php`, we don't have an easy solution to this. :(

Comment: Are you using the Classic Editor or the Block Editor?

Comment: I'm using Classic editor

Answer (score 2):

I hacked the sh*t out of it. Here is my uggliest solution ever to a simple problem. I am not really happy with this, but it will have to do.

For the sake of this example, I will use a custom post type called `book` and we're gonna validate a field called `ISBN`. This solution uses `PHP Session` and `header redirect`.

Here we go...

**Step 1 - Data Validation**

The data validation happens using the filter hook `wp_insert_post_data`, right before the data is inserted in the database. If it is invalid, we set an invalid flag and redirect the user before the data is inserted into the database.

```
function pre_insert_book($data, $postarr)
{
    if ($data['post_type'] === "book" && in_array($data['post_status'], ['publish', 'draft', 'pending']) && !empty($_POST) && isset($_POST['ISBN'])) {
        $ISBN = sanitize_text_field($_POST['ISBN']);
        if (empty($ISBN)) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['POST'] = $_POST;
            header("Location: " . admin_url('post-new.php?post_type=book&invalid=empty_ISBN'));
            exit;
        } elseif (!validade_ISBN($ISBN)) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['POST'] = $_POST;
            header("Location: " . admin_url('post-new.php?post_type=book&invalid=invalid_ISBN'));
            exit;
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'pre_insert_book', 10, 2);
```

**Step 2 - Display error notice**

If an invalid flag is thrown, we display an error to the user. We also preserve the book title so the data isn't lost on form submission. I'm sure this could be done elsewhere.

```
function check_insert_book_error_notices()
{
    global $current_screen, $post;

    if ($current_screen->parent_file === "edit.php?post_type=book" && isset($_GET['invalid'])) {

        session_start();

        // We want to keep the book title like so (and other values if necessary)
        if (isset($_SESSION["POST"]) && isset($_SESSION["POST"]['post_title']))
            $post->post_title = $_SESSION["POST"]['post_title'];

        if (esc_attr($_GET['invalid']) === "empty_ISBN") {
            echo '<div class="error"><p>ISBN number cant be empty</p></div>';
        } elseif (esc_attr($_GET['invalid']) === "invalid_ISBN") {
            echo '<div class="error"><p>ISBN is not valid</p></div>';
        }
    }
}
add_action('admin_notices', 'check_insert_book_error_notices');
```

**Step 3 - Dealing with the ISBN form field and Session**

It's not fun to return to an empty form when a error occurs, nor it is ever a good practice to leave a session open. So we deal with this here.

```
function load_custom_book_meta_boxes()
{
    add_meta_box('isbn-form', 'Book data', array($this, 'custom_form_for_book_post_type'), 'book', 'normal', 'high');
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'load_custom_book_meta_boxes');

function custom_form_for_book_post_type($post)
{

    session_start();

    $ISBN_previous_value = "";
    if (isset($_SESSION["POST"]) && isset($_SESSION["POST"]['ISBN']))
        $ISBN_previous_value = sanitize_text_field($_SESSION["POST"]['ISBN']);

    session_destroy();

    ob_start(); ?>

    <div id="isbn-form-container">
        <form class="isbn-form" method="post" action="">
            <table>
                <tr class="isbn-row">
                    <td><label for="ISBN">Book ISBN</label></td>
                    <td><input type="number" id="ISBN" class="required" name="ISBN" value="<?php echo $ISBN_previous_value; ?>" autocomplete="off" required></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>

<?php ob_end_flush();
}
```

Everything seems to be working fine; I only did a bit of testing and will return later to do some more.

Hope it helps some folks wanting something similar.

Answer (score 1):

I've used jQuery Validate for this sort of thing in a previous project and it worked exactly as I wanted.  You have to enqueue the script and then write the validation out but it really did offer me a great deal of control over what was being done.

https://jqueryvalidation.org

Comment: Yes, I thought about that. Using JS I could disable to publish button, validate data using AJAX and enable button and so on... but if JS is disabled, everything falls apart. It blows my mind how WP is so tight, it needs to be more flexiable, seriously.